# binary literal отрицательное значение

Tags: java

Есть число к примеру `115`, в двоичной системе это число `01110011`, мне нужно, это число объявить литералом так, что бы оно было отрицательным. Я знаю как это сделать с `int`, `short`, `long`, проблема в типе `byte`. Возможно ли инициализировать переменную типа `byte` литералом с отрицательным значением. Что бы при выводе `test1` можно было наблюдать число `-115`?

```
    byte test1 = 0B01110011;
    int test2 = 0B11111111_11111111_11111111_10001101;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что все целочисленные литералы в Java могут быть либо `int`, либо `long`, если литерал завершается символом `L` или `l` ([JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)). Поэтому `0B10001101` воспринимается компилятором как число `141`. Переменная типа `byte` может принимать значения в диапазоне [-128..127], поэтому компилятор не дает присваивать. Код

```
byte c = 0B11111111_11111111_11111111_10001101;
```

при этом ошибок не вызовет, т.к. -115 входит в допустимые значения типа `byte`.

Поэтому придется принудительно приводить тип:

```
byte b = (byte)0B10001101;
```